# Get the dimensions of an ImageDrawable at runtime in Android

Tags: android, image

I have set the background of an Imageview in android (portrait mode) whose dimensions are 400 X 400 pixels. This image looks perfect on a 10" WXGA MDPI tablet (dimensions 800 X 1280). I happen to use the same layout with no modifications in the code on a 7" Nexus 7 (TVDPI 800 X 1280) tablet. The image is looking stretched. Can I programmatically find out the dimensions of the background in the layout on the Nexus 7? I want to mathematically scale down the dimensions of the background such that it looks like a square. I feel that the image background's width looks more than 400 pixels (say X) and the height is also more than 400 pixels (say Y). Also Y > X which makes it looks like a rectangle. How do I find X and Y programmatically in android on the Nexus 7? Please help. Is there a set formula to scale down or scale up the images so that the looks remain consistent on all android phones. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

bellow code will let you take the width of the image and scale it accordingly

```
 try { 

       DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        SCREEN_WIDTH = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        Drawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm);
        float h = ob.getMinimumHeight();
        float w = ob.getMinimumWidth();
        float Hight = (h / w) *SCREEN_WIDTH;
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) Hight);
        // imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(ob);
        } else {
            imageView.setBackground(ob);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than manually calculating the size of the image, have you tried using `android:scaleType="centerInside"` in your xml? You can set the size of the `ImageView` in dp units to keep a consistent size across different screens. The `scaleType` will ensure that the aspect ratio is maintained on scaling. You can also use `android:scaleType="center"` if you would like to prevent scaling and place different sized images in your drawables-xxx folders.